# Creating TeamSite hybrid Application 16

Tags: android, android-keystore, google-play-services, teamsite

I am new to android hybrid application development. I saw the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIZ54sdG7z4 which gives the option in teamsite to create hybrid application. I am trying to follow this method but the video is a demo of team site 8.1 and I have team site 16.1.

The problem I am facing is in the team site under android setting. It asking me,
1. Add Signing Certificate
2. How to download google-services.json
3. Key store password etc.

Please check the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xadRX.png) for the details.

I am new to android. Can someone guide my on this? How do I get this keys?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are your keystore file's aliases and passwords. You can create a new keystore then use the same information in the panel by using `Android Studio Build -> Generate singed APK and create a new keystore.`

Comment: @Mohsen can you guide me on that should i use android keystore or java keystore how do i create them should i use SDK.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your `Keystore` with `jks` format:

```
Android Studio -> Build -> Generate signed APK and create a new keystore
```

Then, you'll see aliases-passwords and etc:

[image]

You just need to use the same password-aliases in the panel when you create a new `Keystore`.

---

There is another key **(server key)** needed which you can find it when you create `google-services.json` from Google console.

Comment: thank for the update. What will be my value for the 'Enter signing certificate passphrase' where can i download 'google-service.json' file?

Comment: Passphrace will be the password which you use for signing the keyStore. Just use the same password for all inputs when you create Keystore then enter the password in the console. About the second question, that will be the Push Notification json file which you'll need to read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client And in Firebase console, it will create `google-services.json` file then you'll need to upload it inside the console.